# recovering an ssh passphrase without generating new pair

Tags: ssh

yesterday I created an ssh key pair (id_rsa/id_rsa.pub) and i put the public key on a few servers for work. Today I ssh-ed into a couple of those servers and it worked using the following command:

`ssh -A user@server`

now I'm trying to ssh into the same server using the same command, but it keeps giving me the dialog to enter a passphrase (or password), but I dont remember what it is. how can I figure it out without generating a new pair? is it the first line in the id_rsa.pub file?

Comment: No, your key is encrypted with it. It's not reversable.

Comment: nah. It is security. What for would the passphrase be if you would be able to recover it without knowing it?